# How can i use PATCH or PUT method in html form on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-binding, laravel-6

i am working on laravel project for practice.
I have got a error while i sending a data in html form by use PUT / PATCH .
I read laravel documentation and i putin html this code line "@method('PUT')" However this error still coming up. Have can i fix this error? Thank you.

**web.php file**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

 Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/course', 'CourseController@index');


Route::post('/course','CourseController@store');

Route::get('/profile','ProfileController@index');

Route::get('/about','HomeController@about');

Route::get('/contact','HomeController@contact');

Route::get('/organization','OrganizationController@index');
Route::get('/organization/create','OrganizationController@create');
Route::post('/organization','OrganizationController@store');
Route::get('/organization/{organizationId}','OrganizationController@show');
Route::get('/organization/{organizationId}/edit','OrganizationController@edit');
Route::patch('/organization/{organizationId}','OrganizationController@update');
```

**OrganizationController(this case update function)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OrganizationController extends Controller
{
public function index(){

    $organizations = \App\Organization::All();

    return view('organization.index',compact('organizations'));
}

public function create(){

    return view('organization.create');
}

public function store(){

    $data = request()->validate([
        'organizationName' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'organizationType' => 'required',
        'email' => 'email',
        'telephoneNo',
        'webpage',
        'organizationEmail'
    ]);

    \App\Organization::create($data);
    return redirect('/organization');
}

public function show($organizationId){
    $organization = \App\Organization::findOrFail($organizationId);

    return view('organization.show',compact('organization'));
}

public function edit(\App\Organization $organization){

    return view('organization.edit',compact('organization'));
}

public function update(\App\Organization $organization){

    $data = request()->validate([
        'organizationName' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'organizationType' => 'required',
        'email' => 'email',
        'telephoneNo',
        'webpage',
        'organizationEmail'
    ]);

    $organization->update($data);
    return redirect('/organization');
}
}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
<h1>Edit Organization</h1>

<form action="/organization/{{ $organization->id }}" method="POST">


    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
    @csrf
    <div>
        <label for="name">Organization Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="organizationName" autocomplete="off" value="{{ 
$organization>organizationName }}">
        @error('name')<p>{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="organizationType">Organization Type</label>
        <input type="text" name="organizationType" autocomplete="off" value="{{ 
$organization>organizationType }}">
        @error('organizationType')<p>{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Organization Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" value="{{ $organization->password 
}}">
        @error('password')<p>{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Telephone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="telephoneNo" autocomplete="off" value="{{ 
$organization>telephoneNo }}">
        @error('telephoneNo')<p>{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="webpage">Web Site</label>
        <input type="text" name="webpage" autocomplete="off" value="{{ $organization->webpage }}">
        @error('webpage')<p>{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="organizationEmail">E-Mail</label>
        <input type="email" name="organizationEmail" autocomplete="off" value="{{ 
$organization>organizationEmail }}">
        @error('email')<p>{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
    </div>

    <button>Save Organization</button>
</form>
```

*I try edit organization this page* http://localhost:8000/organization/1/edit *click save and i see this error.*
[Error page](https://ibb.co/LzZCns2)

Thank you.

Comment: The error message you're getting says that it route being accessed is /organization, not /organization/$id so I think the error is either in the form definition or the route model binding. First, load up your form and make sure the action is being defined properly. it should be `action="/organization/1"`

Secondly in order for route model binding to work the name of the variable in the Route definition, and the name of the variable in the method signature have to match. You're using `organziationId` in the route and `$organization` in the controller update method

Answer (score 1):

Put after your `form` tag this line:

```
@method('PATCH')
```

if you want put make it put

```
 @method('PUT')
```

Comment: I try to this way.But error still coming . I don't understand, however thanks your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The url in your error is `/organization/` without the id, which indeed does not have a patch route.

Try to debug or validate that your edit method actually passes an `$organization` object to your view that has an id set.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try, I've not tested it, but this is how it's all usually work

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Organization;

class OrganizationController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $organizations = Organization::All();
        return view('organization.index',compact('organizations'));
    }
    public function create(){
        return view('organization.create');
    }
    public function store(Request $request){
        try{
            $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'organizationName' => 'required',
                'password' => 'required',
                'organizationType' => 'required',
                'email' => 'email',
                'telephoneNo',
                'webpage',
                'organizationEmail'
            ]);
            Organization::create($validatedData);
             return redirect()->back()->with([
                'status'    => 'success',
                'message'   => 'Organization Created'
            ]);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            return redirect()->back()->with([
                'status'    => 'error',
                'message'   => $e->getMessageBag()
            ]);
        }
    }
    public function show($organizationId = 0){
        $organization = Organization::findOrFail($organizationId);
        if($organization === null){
            return redirect()->back()->with([
                'status'    => 'error',
                'message'   => 'Invalid Organization'
            ])
        }
        return view('organization.show',compact('organization'));
    }
    public function edit($organizationId = 0){
        $organization = Organization::findOrFail($organizationId);
        if($organization === null){
            return redirect()->back()->with([
                'status'    => 'error',
                'message'   => 'Invalid Organization'
            ]);
        }
        return view('organization.edit',compact('organization'));
    }
    public function update(Request $request, $organizationId = 0){
        try{
            $organization = Organization::findOrFail($organizationId);
            if($organization === null){
                return redirect()->back()->with([
                    'status'    => 'error',
                    'message'   => 'Invalid Organization'
                ])
            }
            $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'organizationName' => 'required',
                'password' => 'required',
                'organizationType' => 'required',
                'email' => 'email',
                'telephoneNo',
                'webpage',
                'organizationEmail'
            ]);
            $organization->where('id',$org_id)->update($validatedData);
            return redirect()->back()->with([
                'status'    => 'success',
                'message'   => 'Organization Updated'
            ]);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            return redirect()->back()->with([
                'status'    => 'error',
                'message'   => $e->getMessageBag()
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is `web.php`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

//Auth::routes();
//Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/course', 'CourseController@course')->name('course');
Route::post('/course','CourseController@storeCourse')->name('storeCourse');
Route::get('/profile','ProfileController@profile')->name('profile');
Route::get('/about','HomeController@about')->name('about');
Route::get('/contact','HomeController@contact')->name('contact');

Route::group([
    'prefix'    => 'organization',
    'as'        => 'organization.',
],function(){

    Route::get('/','OrganizationController@index')->name('list');
    Route::get('/create','OrganizationController@create')->name('create');
    Route::post('/store','OrganizationController@store')->name('store');
    Route::get('/show/{organizationId}','OrganizationController@show')->name('show');
    Route::get('/edit/{organizationId}','OrganizationController@edit')->name('edit');
    Route::post('/update/{organizationId}','OrganizationController@update')->name('update');
});
```